# what do you mean by the error "not all arguments converted during string formatting"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to define a function accepts a string and returns the string with every even letter as uppercase and all odds as lowercase but i am getting this error "not all arguments converted during string formatting". I am not able to solve this. Need help.

```
def myfunc(string):
    for i in string:
        if i%2 == 0:
            string[i].upper()
        else:
            string[i].lower()
    return string
```

Comment: There is no string formatting going on in the code you posted. So the error is not from there. The code you did post, however, has quite a few issues. 1> `for i in string` will iterate over the characters in the string, not the indices. 2> `string[i].upper()` returns the upper case character - it doesn't modify the original string. In fact, you need to create a new string out of the original for this to work.

Comment: "There is no string formatting going on in the code you posted." – Yes, there is, on line 3.

Comment: @rdas there *is*, `%` is [`printf`-style string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) if the left hand operand is a string

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ah i missed it. But quite clearly that was not the intention of that piece of code.

Comment: It's an unintentional error @rdas and jonrsharpe :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over the characters of the string by `for i in string`, but instead you want to iterate over the indexes using `for idx in range(len(string))`

You are also taking the modulus of the character, which throws that error, since it thinks you try to format the string (`%` is a string formatting parameter in python as well, more details [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting))

```
In [34]: 'a'%2                                                                                                                                            

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Also `string` is an immutable object, so just doing `string[i].upper()` won't modify it, but you need to save the modified characters into another string

So an updated way of doing it to iterate over the indexes, and convert the characters to `upper` or `lower` accordingly, which gives us a resultant list of characters, which we join and create our modified string

```
def myfunc(string):

    #Convert characters to lower or upper according to conditions and make a list of characters
    li = [string[idx].upper() if idx%2 == 0 else string[idx].lower() for idx in range(len(string))]

    #Join the list back to string and return
    return ''.join(li)

print(myfunc('helloworld'))
```

The output will be

```
HeLlOwOrLd
```

A traditional for loop solution will look the same

```
def myfunc(string):

    #Convert characters to lower or upper according to conditions and make a list of characters
    li = []
    for idx in range(len(string)):
        if idx % 2 == 0:
            li.append(string[idx].upper())
        else:
            li.append(string[idx].lower())

    #Join the list back to string and return
    return ''.join(li)

print(myfunc('helloworld'))
```